# Is there a way to figure out if a form has already been validated?

Tags: bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have some WTForms being used in a flask app. Within templates, I'd like to be able to add Bootstrap's `was-validated` class to the form when a form has already been validated. Is there an object variable that I can look at in the form object?

Comment: have you tried adding your own? `form.was_validated = ""` or `"was-validated"` and then using this `<form class="{{ form.was_validated }}">`. I don't recall ever seeing a native implementation due to the way Flask and FlaskForms works as static renderer